# Handle JSON retrieved data from WCF Data Services

Tags: ajax, json, wcf, jquery

I'm getting some values from a WCF Data Service right, but I don't know how to handle this information. Here goes my ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: "../Services/ChannelWCF.svc/QuotaSet?$filter=month(Date) eq 12",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        console.log(data)
                    }
```

And here that I get from the console:

[image]

An array with 2 objects that I'm not able to handle. I need to get the values from each object of the array returned and save it to another variables. I tried iterating in "data" with $each(....) but I always get "undefined" from the console when I try to print the values of each object.

Comment: Use `$each(data.value, function()`

Comment: Thank you, it was the solution, I only added the .[property] to each object to get the values of the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the data object there are two fields. value is the one you want. Use the following:
    $each(data.value,function(){.....})

Comment: Finally I solved like this:

 $.each(data.value, function(i){
                            console.log(data.value[i]."property")
                        })